# How can I filter out negative comments on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

I find Reddit a useful resource for finding local information, but it is also a source of hateful comments.

Is there a way to pre-emptively filter out mean comments or highly downvoted posts so you don't need to see them?

Comment: Is suggesting an add-on an appropriate answer? I don't know of a way to do it natively, but with the Reddit Enhancement Suite extension you can filter comments, even filtering per subreddit. It's a pretty powerful tool

Comment: @fez yes. Just note what you did in your comment and and provide the alternative.

Comment: I have rolled back your edits to the previous version. Please take the site [tour]. This site operates differently than a discussion forum and unnecessary meta-commentary is discouraged.   iPhone is off-topic here as are questions about developing applications or outsourcing work. See [help/ontopic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Also for the future, assuming edits are on-topic, if a question has been answered, edits should not change the question in such a way as to invalidate  an [otherwise useful answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173696/)

Answer (score 4):

#### Reddit preferences

Go to the Old Reddit preferences page at: https://old.reddit.com/prefs/.

For posts, scroll down to the section called "**Link Options**". There, you will see an option that says, “**don’t show me submissions with a score less than**”. This option allows you to hide posts that have less than the set score. For example, if you set it to -6, you will not see any posts that have a score lower than -6.

[image: screenshot of setting described above]

For comments, go to the "**Comment Options**" section on the same Old Reddit preferences page. There, you can set your desired comment score at the "**don’t show me comments with a score less than**" option.

[image: screenshot of setting described above]

You can choose any number that suits your preference, but keep in mind that posts or comments may have low scores for reasons other than being hateful or offensive. For instance, some posts or comments may be controversial, unpopular, or simply irrelevant to the subreddit. You may want to experiment with different numbers until you find the optimal balance.

#### Blocking users

Another way to avoid seeing hateful or mean content is to **[block the user](https://reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/214548323) who is posting it**. When you block a user, their account and content will be hidden. You won’t see their posts in any subreddit feeds, and their comments will be collapsed (hidden, but can be uncollapsed).

#### Reddit Enhancement Suite

To filter out posts or comments by keyword or other custom criteria, you need to use a browser extension: [Reddit Enhancement Suite (RES)](https://redditenhancementsuite.com/). Note that this feature will only work on the Old Reddit user interface. You can revert back to Old Reddit at your user settings page at https://www.reddit.com/settings/.

In RES settings (the gear icon at the side of the Reddit preferences link), go to "Subreddits" → "filteReddit" or directly at https://www.reddit.com/#res:settings/filteReddit. You can then use various methods of hiding certain posts or comments, such as hiding posts with certain keywords in the title, hiding comments containing certain keywords, hiding posts and comments from specified users, and hiding posts or comments based on complex custom criteria (see the [Custom Filters guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Enhancement/wiki/tutorials/customfilters) for more info).